# POST gives 500 error on registration using Express.js and Passport.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm following a [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#the-posts-page). Basically my app is about creating posts and comments to those posts. I've added a registration to the app using Passport.js, but it's giving me error 500 and i can't figure out what seems to be the problem, i tried with comparing my code with the one from github but no luck, everything seems to be the same. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Error happens when I press the `Register` button on the register page.

Users model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercare: true,
        unique: true
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var exp = new Date(today);
    exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        username: this.username,
        exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
    }, 'SECRET');
};

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkd2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
    var hash = crypto.pbkd2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Passport.js file

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username,'});
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'});
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
```

Registration code from index.js file

```
//registration
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
    }

    var user = new User();

    user.username = req.body.username;

    user.setPassword(req.body.password);

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    return  res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    });
});
```

Angular factory

```
.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {
var auth = {};

auth.saveToken = function (token) {
    $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'] = token;
};

auth.getToken = function (token) {
    return $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'];
};

auth.isLoggedIn = function () {
    var token = auth.getToken();

    if (token) {
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));
        return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

auth.currentUser = function () {
    if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        var token = auth.getToken();
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

        return payload.username;
    }
};

auth.register = function (user) {
    return $http.post('/register', user).success(function (data) {
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
};

auth.logIn = function (user) {
    return $http.post('/login', user).success(function (data) {
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
};

auth.logOut = function () {
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('flapper-news-token');
};

return auth;
}])
```

Angular controller

```
.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $state, auth) {
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.register = function() {
            auth.register($scope.user).error(function(error) {
                $scope.error = error;
            }).then(function() {
                $state.go('home');
            });
        };

        $scope.logIn = function () {
            auth.logIn($scope.user).error(function(error) {
                $scope.error = error;
            }).then(function() {
                $state.go('home');
            });
        };
    })
```

Comment: Someone edited your question and removed some data - like for example the information when the error happens. You may want to take a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40908899/revisions

Comment: @rsp thank you, I've added the info again to the question.

Comment: What error is being logged on the server side before the 500 is returned?  If there's nothing in the console or a file log, try stepping through the code and setting breakpoints so that you can at least narrow the problem down. https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.v2l9dhmce

Comment: @Paul nothing at all, console is clean and then after javascript files are loaded, I press register and bam - 500. Could you point where can I start with breakpoints ?

Comment: Sure, I'd start with the first line in the handler that's responding to '/register' if everything else is/was working.  If that breakpoint doesn't get hit, then it's got to be one of the middleware that's being hit prior to that.  Also, make sure your NODE_ENV is not set to 'production', and you run the app in the foreground, there really should be more getting spit out onto the console when an error happens.

Comment: @Paul I will try with breakpoints now, but I don't understand the other part of your sentence about the end. Could you explain please what I need to do ?

Comment: Sorry, which part are you not understanding?

Comment: @Paul about the node_env smth.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but some node modules look at the NODE_ENV environment variable and behave differently if it is set to production vice development or test.  If you haven't set it, it's probably fine

Comment: @Paul I'm using Ubuntu and didn't configure anything like that. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: @Paul I've found an error and it's ridiculous :)
Instead of pbkd2Sync it should be pbkdf2Sync

Comment: Yep, that's why the debugger is handy. :)  Glad you found it.

Comment: @Paul that's a mystery though, because I've found out about from Network tab in the browser when clicked on the file, but using the node-debugger for Atom it was telling me that my schema was not register, when it frigging was :) Even though thanks for your guidance.